# How do I fix an “The Application Crashed - The Parameter is Incorrect” error in Uwp app?

Tags: uwp, crash

I am getting this error frequently and not able to figure out what is exactly causing it. I haven't found any logs in `Event Viewer` also. Is there any other way I could figure it out.

The application is crashed - The parameter is incorrect

These are some logs in App center

```
ComCallHelpers.Call (__ComObject, RuntimeTypeHandle, Int32)
System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect. The parameter is incorrect. 


Stack traces
System.Runtime.InteropServices
McgMarshal.ThrowOnExternalCallFailed (Int32, RuntimeTypeHandle)__Interop
ComCallHelpers.Call (__ComObject, RuntimeTypeHandle, Int32)__Interop
ForwardComStubs.Stub_11[TThis] (__ComObject, Int32)
Microsoft.AppCenter.Utils
ApplicationLifecycleHelper.<ctor>b__17_1 (Object, UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs)
```

Comment: When did you get the error? Debugging your app or running your app normally? Can you reproduce this issue on your side? Does this issue happen on launch or it happens when you did something in the app?

Comment: It comes randomly after I launch the application. I want to know if this is related to multiple threads running in parallel or somewhere I have missed try-catch ?

Comment: It's hard to confirm if this issue is related to multiple threads based on information we know. My suggestions here: 1) handle the [Application.UnhandledException Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.unhandledexception?view=winrt-19041) in your app. This event could prevent your app from crashing. 2) or you could use the [App Center](https://appcenter.ms/) in your app which will log the exception of your app and give more informations about the error.

Comment: I have used App Center but how to get detailed logs?

Comment: You could check the crash report in App Center. It should contain more information about the error.

Comment: This exception doesn't come into Application.UnhandledException Event

Comment: What the error log in App Center？

Comment: I have added logs in question. I am still not able figure out the issue. Is there any way to handle this exception  (ArgumentException) so that my application doesn't crash

Comment: What's the OS version of your device and what's the target version of your app? Does this happens on other devices?

Comment: OS version - 1903, build - 18362.720 and target version is also the same  and it does happen on other devices too.

Comment: Hello @SauravKumar, did you find the actual cause of that exception?